# Compare user input with grouped data

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny

I want to plot data with a combination of 2 "selectInputs" to choose from. First stage would be "big" or "small", second stage would be the breed.
So I grouped various colums with this function and it will summarise the amount of dogs.

```
filterMethod <- reactive({
if(input$dropdown1=="small"){
  data <- rawData %>%  group_by(breed, name, ID, color) %>%
    summarise(AmountDogs = sum(AmountDogs))
}
```

I created various inputs, for example a selectInput with the breeds to choose from so the user has options that are set.
Now I want to plot the data if the user choose "Terrier" for example.

```
 if(input$dropdown1=="small"){
  plot <- ggplot(data=filterMethod() ??? if $breed==input$breed ???
  }
```

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Would you be able to provide a more complete, working `shiny` app that is reproducible? With example `rawData` (such as by include the result of `dput(head(rawData))`?  It might be helpful to see more of what you are planning to do.

Comment: I don't have anything more than this idea. I just want to find out how it would work if you try to filter data with 2 or more parameters ("small" AND "Terrier").

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely. I think you can remove the `if` statements in both the `reactive` expression as well as around the `ggplot` method. Instead, you can include `filter` if using `dplyr` in your pipe perhaps before the `group_by` statement. For example: `rawData %>% filter(breed == input$breed, size == input$dropdown1) %>% group_by (name, ID, color)` ...etc. Then in `ggplot` you just need `filterMethod()` for data. Would that work for you?